# Error 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier" in plsql

Tags: plsql

I have this procedure:

```
create or replace procedure multiplicate_mts_api_data(number_of_runs NUMBER) AS
v_number_of_runs Number;
v_active_mts_table Varchar2(100);
v_product Varchar2(30) := 'TMP';
Begin
IF number_of_runs > 3 then
  v_number_of_runs := 3;
  else
  v_number_of_runs := number_of_runs;
END IF;

select  value into v_active_mts_table from settings where setting = 'mts.data.table';

For i IN 1..v_number_of_runs 
Loop

execute IMMEDIATE  ' insert into  ' || v_active_mts_table || ' (MTSID ,
                       PRODUCT,
                       SERVICELEVEL,
                       CHARGECODE ,
                       CHARGECODENAME,
                       CHARGECODELOCALNAME,
                       ORIGINZONE,
                       DESTINATIONZONE ,
                       CATEGORY ,
                       SHIPPERCOUNTRY ,
                       ORIGINCOUNTRY ,
                       ORIGINSTATION ,
                       CONSIGNEECOUNTRY ,
                       DESTINATIONCOUNTRY,
                       DESTINATIONSTATION ,
                       AIRLINE ,
                       DIRECTFLIGHT,
                       ROUTING ,
                       FREQUENCY ,
                       DIRECTMOVEMENT,
                       FREQUENCYUNIT ,
                       PRICINGLEVEL ,
                       CAMPAIGNNAME ,
                       TRUCKTYPE ,
                       WEIGHTRATIO ,
                       CURRENCY ,
                       CHARGECODEINFOFLAG,
                       COSTBASE,
                       MINRATE,
                       MAXRATE,
                       UNIT ,
                       RATEPERUNIT,
                       RATEWM ,
                       RATEPERSHIPMENT,
                       RATEPERENTRY ,
                       NUMFREELINESINCLUDED,
                       RATEPERLINEITEM,
                       PERCENTAGE ,
                       CHAGECODEREFERENCE,
                       ALLIN ,
                       RATEFORDEDICATEDVEHICLE ,
                       TRUCKSIZEMETRICTONES,
                       INCLUSIVETOFRT ,
                       ONREQUEST ,
                       NOTES ,
                       TRANSITTIMEUNIT,
                       TRANSITTIME,
                       TRANSITTIMECFSTOPORT ,
                       TRANSITTIMEPORTTOCFS ,
                       VALIDFROM,
                       VALIDTO,
                       WBMIN ,
                       WBMAX,
                       OPERATOR1,
                       AMOUNT1,
                       UNITPRICE1 ,
                       OPERATOR2 ,
                       AMOUNT2 ,
                       UNITPRICE2,
                       OPERATOR3 ,
                       AMOUNT3,
                       UNITPRICE3 ,
                       OPERATOR4,
                       AMOUNT4,
                       UNITPRICE4 ,
                       OPERATOR5,
                       AMOUNT5,
                       UNITPRICE5 ,
                       OPERATOR6,
                       AMOUNT6 ,
                       UNITPRICE6 ,
                       OPERATOR7,
                       AMOUNT7 ,
                       UNITPRICE7 ,
                       OPERATOR8,
                       AMOUNT8 ,
                       UNITPRICE8,
                       OPERATOR9,
                       AMOUNT9 ,
                       UNITPRICE9,
                       OPERATOR10,
                       AMOUNT10 ,
                       UNITPRICE10,
                       DISCOUNT1 ,
                       DENSITY1,
                       DISCOUNT2,
                       DENSITY2,
                       DISCOUNT3,
                       DENSITY3 ,
                       DISCOUNT4 ,
                       DENSITY4  ,
                       DISCOUNT5  ,
                       DENSITY5  ,
                       DISCOUNT6  ,
                       DENSITY6  ,
                       DISCOUNT7 ,
                       DENSITY7  ,
                       DISCOUNT8 ,
                       DENSITY8  ,
                       DISCOUNT9  ,
                       DENSITY9 ,
                       DISCOUNT10  ,
                       DENSITY10  ,
                       DISCOUNT11  ,
                       DENSITY11  ,
                       DISCOUNT12 ,
                       DENSITY12  ,
                       ORIGINSTATIONNAME  ,
                       DESTINATIONSTATIONNAME  ,
                       CARRIER  ,
                       CONTAINERTYPE  ,
                       RATEPERCONTAINER ,
                       RATEPERCONTAINERPERDAY ,
                       FREETIME ,
                       FREETIMEUNIT  ,
                       ORIGINLOCALITY ,
                       ORIGINZIPCODEFROM  ,
                       ORIGINZIPCODETO ,
                       WEIGHTBREAK  ,
                       WEIGHTBREAKUNIT ,
                       TEUTHERESHOLDFORRATEAPPLICABILITY  ,
                       TRANSHIPMENTPORT ,
                       FREQUENCYOFSAILINGS  ,
                       FREQUENCYOFSAILINGSUNIT  ,
                       DESTINATIONLOCALITY  ,
                       DESTINATIONZIPCODEFROM  ,
                       DESTINATIONZIPCODETO  ,
                       UPDATEDTS  ,
                       ORIGINZONELR  ,
                       DESTINATIONZONELR ,
                       CYTOCYTRANSITTIME  ,
                       COMMODITYCODE  ,
                       COMMODITYDESC ,
                       DEMURRAGEANDDETENTIONCOMBINEDFLAG  ,
                       NUMBEROFFREEDAYS  ,
                       EXCLUDEDDAYS  ,
                       RATEPERWMPERDAY  ,
                       SERVICELEVELCODE  ,
                       ADDITIONALCHARGECODESINCLUDED ,
                       AFPTRANSITTIME  ,
                       AFPBASIC  ,
                       AFPMINMFSC  ,
                       AFPRATEPERKGMFSC  ,
                       AFPCOSTWEIGHTBASEMFSC  ,
                       AFPMINMSSC ,
                       AFPRATEPERKGMSSC  ,
                       AFPCOSTWEIGHTBASEMSSC ,
                       AFPRATEPERENTRYOCLE ,
                       AFPRATEPERLINEITEMOCAL ,
                       AFPRATEPERENTRYDCLE ,
                       AFPRATEPERLINEITEMDCAL ,
                       AFPchargeCodeCargoScreening,
                       AFPminCargoScreening,
                       AFPratePerKgCargoScreening,
                       AFPratePerShptCargoScreening,
                       AFPchargeCodeDGSurcharge,
                       AFPminDGSurcharge,
                       AFPratePerKgDGSurcharge,
                       AFPratePerShptDGSurcharge,
                       AFPCargoScreeningFlag,
                       AFPDGSurchargeFlag,
                       AFPCo2e,
                       AFPChargecodeBiofuel,
                       AFPPerKgBiofuel,
                       AFPBioFuelFlag,
                       AFPChargecodeOffsetting,
                       AFPPerKgOffsetting,
                       AFPOffsettingFlag,
                       AFPChargecodeBiofuelOffsetting,
                       AFPPerKgBiofuelOffsetting,
                       AFPBioFuelOffsettingFlag,
                    RATEPERTON ) select ID_GENERATOR.nextval ,
                                        '|| v_product ||' ,
                                        SERVICELEVEL,
                                        CHARGECODE ,
                                        CHARGECODENAME,
                                        CHARGECODELOCALNAME,
                                        ORIGINZONE,
                                        DESTINATIONZONE ,
                                        CATEGORY ,
                                        SHIPPERCOUNTRY ,
                                        ORIGINCOUNTRY ,
                                        ORIGINSTATION ,
                                        CONSIGNEECOUNTRY ,
                                        DESTINATIONCOUNTRY,
                                        DESTINATIONSTATION ,
                                        AIRLINE ,
                                        DIRECTFLIGHT,
                                        ROUTING ,
                                        FREQUENCY ,
                                        DIRECTMOVEMENT,
                                        FREQUENCYUNIT ,
                                        PRICINGLEVEL ,
                                        CAMPAIGNNAME ,
                                        TRUCKTYPE ,
                                        WEIGHTRATIO ,
                                        CURRENCY ,
                                        CHARGECODEINFOFLAG,
                                        COSTBASE,
                                        MINRATE,
                                        MAXRATE,
                                        UNIT ,
                                        RATEPERUNIT,
                                        RATEWM ,
                                        RATEPERSHIPMENT,
                                        RATEPERENTRY ,
                                        NUMFREELINESINCLUDED,
                                        RATEPERLINEITEM,
                                        PERCENTAGE ,
                                        CHAGECODEREFERENCE,
                                        ALLIN ,
                                        RATEFORDEDICATEDVEHICLE ,
                                        TRUCKSIZEMETRICTONES,
                                        INCLUSIVETOFRT ,
                                        ONREQUEST ,
                                        NOTES ,
                                        TRANSITTIMEUNIT,
                                        TRANSITTIME,
                                        TRANSITTIMECFSTOPORT ,
                                        TRANSITTIMEPORTTOCFS ,
                                        VALIDFROM,
                                        VALIDTO,
                                        WBMIN ,
                                        WBMAX,
                                        OPERATOR1,
                                        AMOUNT1,
                                        UNITPRICE1 ,
                                        OPERATOR2 ,
                                        AMOUNT2 ,
                                        UNITPRICE2,
                                        OPERATOR3 ,
                                        AMOUNT3,
                                        UNITPRICE3 ,
                                        OPERATOR4,
                                        AMOUNT4,
                                        UNITPRICE4 ,
                                        OPERATOR5,
                                        AMOUNT5,
                                        UNITPRICE5 ,
                                        OPERATOR6,
                                        AMOUNT6 ,
                                        UNITPRICE6 ,
                                        OPERATOR7,
                                        AMOUNT7 ,
                                        UNITPRICE7 ,
                                        OPERATOR8,
                                        AMOUNT8 ,
                                        UNITPRICE8,
                                        OPERATOR9,
                                        AMOUNT9 ,
                                        UNITPRICE9,
                                        OPERATOR10,
                                        AMOUNT10 ,
                                        UNITPRICE10,
                                        DISCOUNT1 ,
                                        DENSITY1,
                                        DISCOUNT2,
                                        DENSITY2,
                                        DISCOUNT3,
                                        DENSITY3 ,
                                        DISCOUNT4 ,
                                        DENSITY4  ,
                                        DISCOUNT5  ,
                                        DENSITY5  ,
                                        DISCOUNT6  ,
                                        DENSITY6  ,
                                        DISCOUNT7 ,
                                        DENSITY7  ,
                                        DISCOUNT8 ,
                                        DENSITY8  ,
                                        DISCOUNT9  ,
                                        DENSITY9 ,
                                        DISCOUNT10  ,
                                        DENSITY10  ,
                                        DISCOUNT11  ,
                                        DENSITY11  ,
                                        DISCOUNT12 ,
                                        DENSITY12  ,
                                        ORIGINSTATIONNAME  ,
                                        DESTINATIONSTATIONNAME  ,
                                        CARRIER  ,
                                        CONTAINERTYPE  ,
                                        RATEPERCONTAINER ,
                                        RATEPERCONTAINERPERDAY ,
                                        FREETIME ,
                                        FREETIMEUNIT  ,
                                        ORIGINLOCALITY ,
                                        ORIGINZIPCODEFROM  ,
                                        ORIGINZIPCODETO ,
                                        WEIGHTBREAK  ,
                                        WEIGHTBREAKUNIT ,
                                        TEUTHERESHOLDFORRATEAPPLICABILITY  ,
                                        TRANSHIPMENTPORT ,
                                        FREQUENCYOFSAILINGS  ,
                                        FREQUENCYOFSAILINGSUNIT  ,
                                        DESTINATIONLOCALITY  ,
                                        DESTINATIONZIPCODEFROM  ,
                                        DESTINATIONZIPCODETO  ,
                                        UPDATEDTS  ,
                                        ORIGINZONELR  ,
                                        DESTINATIONZONELR ,
                                        CYTOCYTRANSITTIME  ,
                                        COMMODITYCODE  ,
                                        COMMODITYDESC ,
                                        DEMURRAGEANDDETENTIONCOMBINEDFLAG  ,
                                        NUMBEROFFREEDAYS  ,
                                        EXCLUDEDDAYS  ,
                                        RATEPERWMPERDAY  ,
                                        SERVICELEVELCODE  ,
                                        ADDITIONALCHARGECODESINCLUDED ,
                                        AFPTRANSITTIME  ,
                                        AFPBASIC  ,
                                        AFPMINMFSC  ,
                                        AFPRATEPERKGMFSC  ,
                                        AFPCOSTWEIGHTBASEMFSC  ,
                                        AFPMINMSSC ,
                                        AFPRATEPERKGMSSC  ,
                                        AFPCOSTWEIGHTBASEMSSC ,
                                        AFPRATEPERENTRYOCLE ,
                                        AFPRATEPERLINEITEMOCAL ,
                                        AFPRATEPERENTRYDCLE ,
                                        AFPRATEPERLINEITEMDCAL ,
                                        AFPchargeCodeCargoScreening,
                                        AFPminCargoScreening,
                                        AFPratePerKgCargoScreening,
                                        AFPratePerShptCargoScreening,
                                        AFPchargeCodeDGSurcharge,
                                        AFPminDGSurcharge,
                                        AFPratePerKgDGSurcharge,
                                        AFPratePerShptDGSurcharge,
                                        AFPCargoScreeningFlag,
                                        AFPDGSurchargeFlag,
                                        AFPCo2e,
                                        AFPChargecodeBiofuel,
                                        AFPPerKgBiofuel,
                                        AFPBioFuelFlag,
                                        AFPChargecodeOffsetting,
                                        AFPPerKgOffsetting,
                                        AFPOffsettingFlag,
                                        AFPChargecodeBiofuelOffsetting,
                                        AFPPerKgBiofuelOffsetting,
                                        AFPBioFuelOffsettingFlag,
                                        RATEPERTON  from ' || v_active_mts_table || ' where product != '|| v_product;


End loop;


End;
```

When I try to run it, I obtain error:

```
Error report -
ORA-00904: "TMP": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "DEV_CRDB.MULTIPLICATE_MTS_API_DATA", line 17
ORA-06512: at line 2
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Can someone please give me a point how to solve this issue? If I try to run this insert via sql developer, it runs smoothly. Im beginner in plsql, so please be patient if this is dummy question. Maybe there is a problem with sql insert concatenation, I dont know. Thank you Petr

Comment: read up on using proper bind variables with execute immediate and USING clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be it:

Looking at the error:

```
ORA-00904: "TMP": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "DEV_CRDB.MULTIPLICATE_MTS_API_DATA", line 17
```

You're assigning TMP to a variable here:

```
v_product Varchar2(30) := 'TMP';
```

and then referencing v_product here:

```
                   RATEPERTON ) select ID_GENERATOR.nextval ,
                                        '|| v_product ||' ,
                                        SERVICELEVEL,
```

It looks like the above line is causing the error. The reason is that there are no quotes around "v_product" - just the quotes needed for the concatenation. So the select becomes

```
...
  SELECT ID_GENERATOR.nextval , 
         TMP,
         SERVICELEVEL,
...
```

and there probably is not column called "TMP" in that table which raises the error.

My guess is you want to select the value "TMP", and *not the column* TMP. The value "TMP" needs to be enclosed in quotes and those quotes need to be escaped so try the following instead. :

```
                   RATEPERTON ) select ID_GENERATOR.nextval ,
                                        '''|| v_product ||''' ,
                                        SERVICELEVEL,
```

Give that a try.